# Converting videos to AVI with AVIDemux for compatibility

Tags: compatibility, video-conversion, avi

I am trying to convert a couple of short videos to AVI (XviD) using AVIDemux. I find that while the resulting videos play fine in VLC, they do not play in an XviD DVD player (nor presumably Xbox 360, PS3, etc.). In fact, they do not even show in Windows Explorer (that is, Explorer cannot read their metadata or display thumbnails).

I tried using all three of the *AVI Muxer Output Format* options, but none worked.

Does anyone know what settings to use to produce compatible AVIs with AVIDemux? (I found an old thread where someone complained about AVIs not working on Xbox, but that was a few years ago from an older version.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version I was using (2.6.0 beta) seems to have a bug that produces non-standard AVI containers.

Updating to the [latest nightly](http://www.avidemux.org/nightly/win32) has fixed the bug and produces AVI files that can be read by Windows Explorer.

One caveat though, my tests have found that sometimes AVIs produced even with the nightly do not show up correctly in Windows Explorer unless you specifically make a selection; simply leaving the selection absent will indeed select the whole video, but then the resulting video is unreadable by Explorer (this is not *always* the case and seems to depend on the source video, but my tests were consistent, so always making a selection, even if it’s the whole video is a good idea).